# Suggestions on best way to see what bandwidth hogs may be?

Tags: bandwidth

Approaching some bandwidth limits on our VPS. Is there a good way to narrow down which scripts may be sucking up the most bandwidth?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What OS?

For Windows, [`showtraf`](http://sourceforge.net/projects/showtraf/)

For linux, [`iptraf`](http://iptraf.seul.org/)

For FreeBSD or OpenBSD, [`pftop`](http://www.eee.metu.edu.tr/~canacar/pftop/)

Answer (score 0):

For looking at an ethernet pipe, [nfsen/nfdump](http://wiki.xdroop.com/space/Linux/Installing+nfsen).